# How to return object from rest service in java?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, jersey

What is the best way to return a value of a method of rest service ? A java object, json string or with Response?

For example, these examples are implemented with api jersey (maven):

1) Return java object (mapped to json):

```
@GET
@Path("/getUser")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public UserVO getUser() {

    UserVO user = new UserVO();
    user.setValid(true);
    user.setName("Peter");

    return user;
}
```

2) Return a json string:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUser")
public String getUser() {

    UserVO user = new UserVO();
    user.setValid(true);
    user.setName("Peter");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonResp = gson.toJson(user);

    return jsonResp;
}
```

3) Return with response json:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUser")
public Response getUser() {

    UserVO user = new UserVO();
    user.setValid(true);
    user.setName("Peter");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonResp = gson.toJson(user);

    return Response.ok(jsonResp, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

What is the difference between these 3? Which is better to use ?

(Considering it will be consumed from javascript)

Answer (score 0):

All three options seem valid, but the first one is in my opinion more consistent because you're using an API (jersey) and this @produces annotation is the common way to use that API.

Moreover it won't make you dependant of another lib, GSON, which you could ultimately remove from your classpath if it isn't used elsewhere.